# Are pseudo-devices implemented as device drivers within the kernel?

Tags: unix, drivers

I kinda wonder if pseduo-devices like /dev/null and /dev/zero are implemented as device drivers within the kernel. I'm sure they are, but not exactly 100% sure. Both /dev/null and /dev/zero device files have same major number but different minor numbers; they use the same driver which doesn't really drive a physical hardware and the minor numbers to specify different functionality within the driver.

Is my hypothesis right?

Comment: Yes; at least classically, all devices — pseudo or not — were implemented as device drivers in the kernel.  Frequently, the implementations of the support functions were minimal for the pseudo-devices.  The `write` code for `/dev/null` does nothing successfully (and the same is likely true of `/dev/zero`); the read code for `/dev/null` reports 'no data'; the read code for `/dev/zero` zeroes the buffer that it is given.  And so on.  Things may have changed a little over the last 20 years, but that's more or less how it used to be and how I'd expect it still to be (but I live to be surprised).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler On the Linux system I'm using and maybe on other Linux systems `/dev/null`, `/dev/zero`  and `/dev/random` all have the same major number though.

Comment: OK; and what's the problem?  They have different minor numbers, and as a result do different things from each other, just as different disk drives may share a major number but the minor numbers distinguish different subsections of the main device, or even different drives altogether.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yea that's right. I'm just saying that in Linux the mentioned pseudodevices use the same driver.  Your first command should really be an answer, if you wish post it as an answer so I accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least classically, all devices — pseudo or not — were implemented as device drivers in the kernel. Frequently, the implementations of the support functions were minimal for the pseudo-devices. The write code for `/dev/null` does nothing successfully (and the same is likely true of `/dev/zero`); the read code for `/dev/null` reports 'no data'; the read code for `/dev/zero` zeroes the buffer that it is given. And so on. Things may have changed a little over the last 20 years, but that's more or less how it used to be and how I'd expect it still to be (but I live to be surprised).

> On the Linux system I'm using, and maybe on other Linux systems, `/dev/null`, `/dev/zero` and `/dev/random` all have the same major number though.

That needn't be a problem.  They have different minor numbers, and as a result can and do do different things from each other, just as different disk drives may share a major number but the minor numbers distinguish different subsections of the main device, or even different drives altogether.

On a Mac (running macOS Sierra 10.12.5), `/dev/null` and `/dev/zero` share the same major number, and `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` share the same major number that's different from the other two.

```
crw-rw-rw-  1 root      wheel            3,   2 Jul 10 20:10 /dev/null
crw-rw-rw-  1 root      wheel           14,   0 Jun 13 13:34 /dev/random
crw-rw-rw-  1 root      wheel           14,   1 Jun 13 13:34 /dev/urandom
crw-rw-rw-  1 root      wheel            3,   3 Jun 13 13:34 /dev/zero
```

More intriguing is that there are a number of devices with the same major and minor numbers:

```
crw-------  1 jleffler  staff            0,   0 Jul  8 01:54 /dev/console
crw-rw-rw-  1 root      wheel            0,   0 Jun 13 13:34 /dev/fbt
crw-rw-rw-  1 root      wheel            0,   0 Jun 13 13:34 /dev/lockstat
crw-rw-rw-  1 root      wheel            0,   0 Jun 13 13:34 /dev/machtrace
crw-rw-rw-  1 root      wheel            0,   0 Jun 13 13:34 /dev/profile
crw-rw-rw-  1 root      wheel            0,   0 Jun 13 13:34 /dev/sdt
crw-rw-rw-  1 root      wheel            0,   0 Jun 13 13:34 /dev/systrace
```

I'm not sure how those distinguish what they're supposed to do.